# Annotation doesn't show

Tags: swift, xcode, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotation

After going to the map view controller the UITabBarItem must perform an action after what the annotation must be added to the map

class MapViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var middleMapButton: UITabBarItem!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let regionInMeters: Double = 10000

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    ecoMapButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "plus.circle")
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    middleMapButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "mappin.circle")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    checkLocationServices()
    
}
```

Here is the action for that tab bar item

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.881832, longitude: -87.623177)
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Here goes some location privacy actions

```
func setupLocationManager() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
}

func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
    if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}

func checkLocationServices() {
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        setupLocationManager()
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    } else {
        
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that annotation is in your `setRegion`? Also it doesn't seem that you are setting a delegate to the tabBarController, so your method is not called

Comment: There is UITabBarDelegate but it doesn;t work even with that
class MapViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate

Comment: You have to assign that `delegate` so the UITabViewController, check delegation pattern. It is very common in iOS

Comment: I have to assign it in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I did like that

middleMapButton.delegate = self